# Why is undefined when input captured?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to capture user input then put it in local storage. I want listen to every element on the page if there is input then grab it. But when i tried to test it, it is returning "undefined" as value. Why?

```
(function () {
  $(document).on("input", function () {
    data = document.getElementsByName("*").value;
    localStorage.setItem("test", data);
  });
})();
```

Comment: getElement**s**ByName returns *multiple* elements, so `.value` makes no sense in that case.

Comment: Try: `let data = $(this).val()`